# Is it possible to restrict the number of copies which can be printed from a PDF?

Tags: pdf, printing

I have an application where a user can download a PDF for printing.

I want to be able to restrict the number of copies that can be printed.

Is it possible to digitally sign/restrict a PDF in this way?

Comment: What would stop your users from simply putting those "limited copies" in their copying machine?

Comment: Nothing of course, although for some content this is against the law.

Answer (score 2):

Yes but you will need to use PDF DRM.

Most would consider DRM is a bad thing, and it is breakable.

You will probably have to pay a company to use their DRM software.

Click [here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=pdf+drm&meta=&btnG=Google+Search)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no. That would mean that you have to write somewhere the information of how many times the PDF has been printed. All that would be required to print it more time would be to make a copy of the file before printing, and print the copy. The original would still have the information that it is not printed.

Worst case, it is always possible to print it once and make xerox copies after, so you dont gain much by being able to restrict the number of prints.

Comment: This is incorrect, the number of printings can be restricted and this is commonly used, e.g. for academic paper PDF's where the person downloading will only be able to print a copy once.

Comment: It is easy to come up with the idea of giving the PDF a unique identify (an embedded GUID, encrypted or otherwise hidden so it's hard to change, I guess), and then putting the print-counter on a remote server. So it doesn't *have* to be in the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to resrict the number of copies that can be printed.

The legal solution of copyright law is probably more appropriate than a technological one which may be questionable and/or annoying to customers.

IEEE has a solution they use for their technical library documents, namely they are now merging the original document with a footer saying "Permission to use this document granted to _____@____.com" before serving it to everyone -- it doesn't stop someone from printing out the file or copying the file, but it does put the reader's name on the document so that if someone does print out 50,000 copies it will have their name on it & hence make legal enforcement of copyright law a little easier.